# Keep trace/span across CompletableFuture in Micrometer (micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave)

Tags: spring-boot, completable-future, distributed-tracing, micrometer-tracing

I am using Micrometer tracing library with Spring boot for distributed tracing.
It works great with normal execution *when we have execution in single threaded environment but when we use multithreading environment like `CompletableFuture` then the **trace information** is not passed to threads and respective log has empty **traceId/spanId***

gradle dependency

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
 implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
```

MainApplication class

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

  @SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class MainApplication {

  @GetMapping("async")
  String helloAsync() {
    log.info("hello from rest endpoint[GET]");
    CompletableFutureUtil.performAsyncOperation();
    return "hi";
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

CompletableFutureUtil class

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class CompletableFutureUtil {

  public static void performAsyncOperation() {
    // Create a CompletableFuture and simulate an async process
    CompletableFuture<String> future =
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> {
              // Simulate the asynchronous process (replace with your actual logic)
              log.info("inside CompletableFuture.supplyAsync..");
              simulateAsyncOperation();
              log.info("returning from CompletableFuture.supplyAsync..");
              // Simulate a successful result
              return "Simulated result";
            });

    // Attach a callback for successful completion
    future.thenAccept(
        result -> {
          logInfo("Async process completed successfully. Result: " + result);
        });

    // Attach a callback for exceptional completion
    future.exceptionally(
        exception -> {
          logError("Async process failed. Reason: " + exception.getMessage());
          return null;
        });

    // Simulate some other work while the async process is ongoing
    logInfo("Some other work is being done...");

    logInfo("Main thread ended.");
  }

  private static void simulateAsyncOperation() {
    // Simulate some asynchronous operation (replace with your actual logic)
    logInfo("Simulating async operation...");
    try {
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2); // Simulate some delay
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
  }

  private static void logInfo(String message) {
    log.info("[INFO] " + message);
  }

  private static void logError(String message) {
    log.error("[ERROR] " + message);
  }
}
```

the logs generated when called `HTTP:localhost:8080/async`

```
2023-12-09T00:29:29.117+05:30 " INFO [content-publisher-service,6573679104ea6b2868558e3949953a1e,68558e3949953a1e]" 42181 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.c.a.c.p.service.BootsApplication       : hello from rest endpoint[GET]
2023-12-09T00:29:29.121+05:30 " INFO [content-publisher-service,6573679104ea6b2868558e3949953a1e,68558e3949953a1e]" 42181 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.c.a.c.p.s.util.CompletableFutureUtil   : [INFO] Some other work is being done...
2023-12-09T00:29:29.121+05:30 " INFO [content-publisher-service,,]" 42181 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.c.a.c.p.s.util.CompletableFutureUtil   : inside CompletableFuture.supplyAsync..
2023-12-09T00:29:29.122+05:30 " INFO [content-publisher-service,6573679104ea6b2868558e3949953a1e,68558e3949953a1e]" 42181 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.c.a.c.p.s.util.CompletableFutureUtil   : [INFO] Main thread ended.
2023-12-09T00:29:29.122+05:30 " INFO [content-publisher-service,,]" 42181 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.c.a.c.p.s.util.CompletableFutureUtil   : [INFO] Simulating async operation...
2023-12-09T00:29:31.122+05:30 " INFO [content-publisher-service,,]" 42181 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.c.a.c.p.s.util.CompletableFutureUtil   : returning from CompletableFuture.supplyAsync..
2023-12-09T00:29:31.122+05:30 " INFO [content-publisher-service,,]" 42181 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.c.a.c.p.s.util.CompletableFutureUtil   : [INFO] Async process completed successfully. Result: Simulated result
```

Comment: You need to use such a method from CompletableFuture that accepts an Executor of some kind. Then use Micrometer's Context Propagation library to wrap the Executor.

Comment: Can you please share any example of that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use such a method from CompletableFuture that accepts an Executor of some kind. Then use Micrometer's Context Propagation library to wrap the  Executor. Example https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/brewery/blob/1bfca4ed62bd3d3b7a7fb6f1b70179a0154382f7/brewing/src/main/java/io/spring/cloud/samples/brewery/aggregating/IngredientsAggregator.java#L45-L53

```
CompletableFuture completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            ingredientsCollector.collectIngredients(order, processId).stream()
                    .filter(ingredient -> ingredient != null)
                    .forEach((Ingredient ingredient) -> {
                        log.info("Adding an ingredient [{}] for order [{}] , processId [{}]", ingredient);
                        ingredientWarehouse.addIngredient(ingredient);
                    });
            return null;
        }, ContextSnapshot.captureAll().wrapExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)));
```

Comment: I am using Kafka to send the message and there I can't find a way where I can send my custom executor. Is there anyway in this case?

Comment: Does kafka accept an executor  of some sort (most likely)? If yes, you can pass the instrumented executor for Kafka to use.